# Sonar rule S2699: Not all asserts are recognized as valid assertions

Tags: java, sonarqube

We are running Sonarqube 5.6.1 with the Java Plugin 4.1 and having some troubles using the Sonar rule S2699 (Test should include assertions).

Using this example test class

```
import mypackage.Citit1543Dummy;
import mypackage.Citit1543OtherDummy;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.isIn;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.lessThan;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.notNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class Citit1543Test {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        assert true;
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Assert.assertTrue(1 > (2-3));
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        Assert.assertFalse(1 > (100-1));
    }

    @Test
    public void test4() {
        Assert.assertThat("test", 1, is(1));
    }

    @Test
    public void test5() {
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[0], new String[0]);
    }

    @Test
    public void test6() {
        Assert.assertEquals(1 > 0, true);
    }

    @Test
    public void test7() { // asserts in another method
        test7asserts(1, 1);
    }

    private void test7asserts(int a, int b) {
        Assert.assertTrue(a == b);
    }

    @Test
    public void test8() {
        test8asserts(1, 2);
    }

    private void test8asserts(int a, int b) {
        Assert.assertNotSame(a, b);
    }

    @Test
    public void test9() {
        Citit1543Dummy dummy = new Citit1543Dummy();
        dummy.otherDummy = mock(Citit1543OtherDummy.class);
        dummy.doSomething();
        verify(dummy.otherDummy, times(1)).doSomething();
    }

    @Test
    public void test10() {
        Citit1543Dummy dummy = new Citit1543Dummy();
        dummy.otherDummy = mock(Citit1543OtherDummy.class);
        dummy.doSomething();
        test10verifies(dummy.otherDummy);
    }

    private void test10verifies(Citit1543OtherDummy otherDummy) {
        verify(otherDummy, times(1)).doSomething();
    }

    @Test
    public void test11() {
        Assert.assertThat("test", "", not(1));
    }

    @Test
    public void test12() {
        Assert.assertThat("test", 1, lessThan(2));
    }

    @Test
    public void test13() {
        Long[] arr = new Long[] { 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L };
        assertThat("Just testing", arr, is(new Long[] {
            1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
        }));
    }
}
```

our Sonarqube instance flags the test cases `test1` (assert statement not recognized), `test7` (assert statements in another method), `test8` (same)  , `test10` (Mockitos `verify` in another method), `test11` and `test13` as methods without assertions. I'm pretty sure that there are a lot more methods which aren't recognized (yes, unfortunately we use a bunch of different mocking/testing framework across our projects).

For now, we started to `//NOSONAR` whenever one of the asserts/verifies aren't recognized.
Is there an easy way to include these methods to be recognized as valid asserts?

Comment: The test1 flag is definitely not a false positive. asserts are ignored unless you turn them on with '-ea' when running your tests. And they're not meant to verify assertions in unit tests. So you should fix that bug, not ignore it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of your stated issues are known and indeed (in some form of another) marked as FP:
test1: The current flow analysis ignores assert statements. See [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/En0C4u6xe_Q/W6S2wuxoBQAJ) over at the groups.

The cases test7, test8 and test10 are related to the lack of not having cross-procedural analysis: They are valid cases but the current flow doesn't know that (ex.) test7assert is a valid assert statement for another method. See [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/PXZeiZgDFMc/E_eXd8oMAgAJ) over at the groups.

Your other cases also produce false positives in the tests of S2699. I'd expect that once a SonarSource dev reads this topic that they'll create a ticket to resolve the cases in test11/13. But as I'm not a dev of them I can't guarantee that of course.

As to :

> Is there an easy way to include these methods to be recognized as valid asserts?

No, the valid assertions are defined within the code of S2699 and are not a parameter. Some of your cases will require a more complex flow analysis whilst the last couple just seem to boil down to some missing definitions or too strict definitions, but I didn't deep-dive into the reasons why they produce FPs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems we have to wait until this is fixed in the Sonar Java Plugin.